# Update page JSON data get on drop down change

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I am currently running into the following issue: 
I created a simple visualisation with d3.js. The data for the visualisation gets pulled from a MySQL server via JSON/PHP.

On the page that gets presented to the user there is a simple dropdown menu that lets the user decide for which year they want to data to be displayed.
On the initial page load just works just fine, the default value from the dropdown menu gets passed down to the "yearchoice" variable, which in turn gets passed through to the JSON request. The problem at this point is however that when the user selects another year from the dropdown nothing happens. The reasons I assume is that I have to add some "onSelect" or "onClick" code to force a new data pull and refresh the visualisation. However so far I have had no luck in solving this. Please see the relevant (simplified) code below:

HTML

```
<select id="DropDownList">
 <option value="2014">2014</option>
 <option value="2015">2015</option>
</select>
```

d3.js

```
//select year
var yearchoice = d3.select("#DropDownList").node().value;

// Get the data
d3.json("allspending.php?year=" + yearchoice, function(error, data) {
    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.date = parseDate(d.date);
        d.amount = +d.amount;
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok Figured it out.

Used the below to monitor for changes in the dropdown.

```
d3.select('#DropDownList')
  .on('change', function() {
    var yearchoice = eval(d3.select(this).property('value'));
    updateLegend(yearchoice);
});
```

and put the entire rendering of the graph in a function (update legend) that gets run everytime the dropdown changes values.